# Is QGIS Server Properly Installed?

Tags: qgis, qgis-server

I just installed QGIS server using the instructions provided [here](http://anitagraser.com/2012/04/06/qgis-server-on-windows7-step-by-step/). I am pretty sure that I have installed QGIS properly, but I am not sure. I am using Windows 7, and XAMPP. I typed the following into my browser:

`http://localhost:8081/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&`

And I get a page that begins like this:

```
<WMS_Capabilities xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wms" version="1.3.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wms http://qgis.org/wms_1_3_0.xsd">
<Service>
<Name>WMS</Name>
<!--  Human-readable title for pick lists  -->
<Title>QGIS mapserver</Title>
<!--
 Narrative description providing additional information 
-->
<Abstract>A WMS service with QGIS mapserver</Abstract>
<KeywordList>
<Keyword>QGIS mapserver</Keyword>
</KeywordList>
<!--
 Top-level web address of service or service provider. 
 See also OnlineResource elements under <DCPType>. 
-->
<OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.sourcepole.ch/"/>
<!--  Contact information  -->
```

I am pretty sure this is what I am supposed to get, so I assumed that what I was doing was correct. After that, I placed a QGIS file in `C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\bin` and tried to view this by putting:

`http://www.localhost:8801/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&map=C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/bin/LakeCountyBlight.qgs&`

in my browser.

I wasn't sure if that was what I was supposed to do, so I went into QGIS > vector > add WMS/WMTS > new > URL > `localhost:8801/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&map=C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/bin/LakeCountyBlight.qgs`

When I did that, I got the error message:

```
Failed to download capabilities:
Download of capabilities failed: Host www.localhost not found
```

I'm not sure why nothing is happening. One thing that might be a problem is that my computer has both IIS, and Apache on it. I set IIS and Apache to different ports by going into the httpd.conf files. However, I also had to change the httpd.conf file for QGIS server to something different for Xampp to get it to work. I was wondering if that was the problem, and if so, how would I fix it?

Comment: Why are you prefixing the web address with www? Your server address is http://localhost.

Comment: I tried doing it both ways, just to see if maybe adding the webaddress would change. I got the same results both ways.

Comment: Please edit your question according to @drunkenwagoner remark.

Comment: I think I solved the problem. I was running QGIS server from one drive, and had the documents saved in another drive, which seemed the computer then could not find. After moving the .qgs file to the C drive, I could get a capabilities-XML like I was supposed to.

Answer (score 2):

> I placed a QGIS file in C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\bin and tried to view
>   this by putting:
>
> http://www.localhost:8801/qgis/qgis_mapserv.fcgi.exe?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&map=C:/OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/bin/LakeCountyBlight.qgs&

You can't **view** any data by doing a GetCapabilities request on it.  If everything is configured correctly then you should get an XML response for the service that includes information about the data held in `LakeCountyBlight.qgs`.

However, as per your error, your request is incorrect because you have `http://www.localhost:8801` it should be `http://localhost:8801`, that is without the `www`.